# How to do Insert/Delete remotely through a SPARQL endpoint?

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data, triplestore, federated-queries

Is there a way to update data by (`INSERT DATA` and `DELETE DATA`) remotely through a SPARQL endpoint? I'm aware that we can use `SERVICE` to do distributed and federated query, but I got errors when i tried to use `SERVICE` to remotely update data as:

```
INSERT DATA
{SERVICE <SparqlEndpoint1> {
subject, predicate, object
}}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPARQL - Insert data from remote endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615446/sparql-insert-data-from-remote-endpoint)

Comment: @StanislavKralin - This is not a duplicate. The other questioner wanted to select data from a remote endpoint, for insertion into the local endpoint. This questioner wants to insert data to the remote endpoint, through the local endpoint.

Comment: And why can't you send the query to the endpoint then? The URL of the endpoint is obvisouly known, thus, I don't understand the use case.

Comment: @AKSW, i tried to update a distributed triplestore via the SPARQL interface provided by a local triplestore,is there any way i can do this? thanks.

Comment: Not via SPARQL. Which distributed triple store is this? Why can't you use the interface of this triple store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Federated SPARQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/) `SERVICE` clause only supports `SELECT` operations.  `SERVICE` clauses cannot be used for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or other [SPARQL Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/) operations on remote endpoints.  See the [SPARQL 1.1 grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rServiceGraphPattern) and the other linked documents for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)